# How Many Prime Numbers of the Form $\underbrace{1...111}_\text{p}$ Are There?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The other day, I encountered a theorem that suggested if a number of the form $\underbrace{1...111}_\text{p}$ is prime, then $p$ is prime as well. The proof was rather simple but it got me thinking about the following: How many prime numbers of the form $\underbrace{1...111}_\text{p}$ are there?I tried using the fact that $\underbrace{1...111}_\text{p} = \underbrace{1...111}_\text{p-1} * 10 + 1$ but I don't know what to do from here.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So fare as i know is this Problem unsolved yet!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I thoroughly searched the web and quite a few number theory books and although there were many theorems involving numbers of the form $\underbrace{1...111}_\text{p}$ and whether they're prime or not, this is a "stronger" conjecture.

Comment: @BornaGhahnoosh See the conjecture [here](https://primes.utm.edu/glossary/page.php?sort=Repunit). There are more resources linked on the [OEIS page](https://oeis.org/A004023).

Comment: These are called [prime repunits](https://primes.utm.edu/glossary/page.php?sort=Repunit) and it is unknown whether or not there are infinitely many.  The link I gave suggests some heuristics which may justify conjecturing the infinitude, but nothing is known.

Comment: @Lulu Do I close this question or do I delete it?

Comment: You can try to find out a solution!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I'm 14 now and I've been practically obsessed with prime numbers since I was 12. It's my dream to prove a major prime conjecture! I'll keep this question open so maybe one day, I could prove this conjecture:)

Comment: https://primes.utm.edu/notes/proofs/MerDiv.html  is the case for base 2, might be hard to generalize to base 10.

Comment: I wish you all the best for this.

Comment: @BornaGhahnoosh a more pleaseful writing of this is $10^{p}-1=9q $with $p,q$ primes :).

Comment: @BornaGhahnoosh This is a duplicate. Nine so-called rep-unit primes are knwon (five of them were proven to be prime).

Comment: Sorry to take so long to reply.  I don't think there's any harm in leaving the question up.  People may not be aware of the conjecture.  For that matter, I don't know if anyone is really working at it, so it may be the case that someone new could make some progress.  Be aware, though, that, other than in arithmetic progressions, nobody has every been able to say much about primes.  Nobody knows if there are infinitely many primes of the form $n^2+1$, for instance, though one would guess that there were.

Comment: @BornaGhahnoosh One can be said for sure : If you will actually be successful in solving this conjecture (no matter with which final result), you will become famous ! Such questions (primes of a particular form without an obvious reason why only finite many can be prime because of forced factors) are usually out of reach with current knowledge. In fact, for the poylnomials, only degree $1$ was solved by Dirichlet. That said, I do not want to discourage you to try it. In particular , the problem with the rep-units, will be of great interest !